# How to create a webview and radio buttons blow it in android layout?

Tags: android

I am new to android. I want to create a webview and below that radio buttons dynamically. How can I create android layout for this? I need to display these in a listview. Help me...

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `FrameLayout` in which you can create a `WebView` and a `RadioGroup` as child views.And set the gravity of `RadioGroup` to bottom.In this case both views `WebView` and `RadioGroup` will be overlapped.

But if you don't want them to be overlapped then use `LinearLayout` instead of `FrameLayout` and set the `layout_weight="1"` to `WebView`.

Hope this will help.